# Removing all identifying info before sharing a copy of an excel sheet on a blog

Tags: microsoft-excel, privacy, sharing, privacy-protection

There is an Excel Workbook I have created which I want to share on a blog page of mine (it's a static page created on github.io)

What is the best way to share an excel Workbook?

- Should I just provide a download link on the page for people to download it? Or are there any other options I can explore?

Also what do I need to do to remove all identifiable information from the workbook before I upload it?

It's created using Office Home & Student 2016.

Comment: Try googling "remove office document metadata" for the file. For sharing you can try both normal file hosting on GH pages or one of the fancier third-party options like Google Docs and OneDrive with its preview/editing things.

Comment: @MingyeWang - won't sharing on One Drive expose my account id & any other personal information?

Comment: Yeah, it will. (Uh... Are burner accounts still a thing in 2021, or are they requiring mobile phone verification for registration now?)

Comment: @MingyeWang - google accounts now seem to require mobile verification. I will check if Microsoft accounts also require the same.

Answer (score 0):

you may be looking for this:
[Embed an Excel workbook on your web page or blog from OneDrive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-it-embed-an-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-onedrive-804e1845-5662-487e-9b38-f96307144081)
Just need to make sure not to add any important private information to the file before embedding it.

Comment: Questions should be self containing, please include key information from the link.

Comment: `Just need to make sure not to add any important private information to the file before embedding it.` - but Excel documents already contain info which we don't explicitly add. How to be sure no info is escaping